# Синхронизация записи/чтения файлов

Tags: c++, файлы, c++11

Процессу необходимо сообщать о своем состоянии другим процессам на этой же машине. Для этого он пишет соответствующую информацию в файл, каждый раз переписывая его полностью.

Чтобы состояние было целостным, в конец файла добавляется контрольная сумма, и читатели, в случае ошибки контрольной суммы, перечитывают файл (это может означать, что писатель начал обновление файла, и часть файла уже переписана).

Вопрос - есть ли более элегантное решение, без привязки к платформе, для разделения доступа к файлу.

Дополнительный вопрос - есть ли гарантия, что читатели будут видеть изменения в том же порядке, в каком их вносит писатель (т.е. стоит ли ещё добавлять какой-то порядковый номер записи помимо контрольной суммы).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если уже хотите на файлах, то делайте где то так - процесс пишет в временный файл, а когда понимает, что уже все записал и закрыл файл, просто удаляет исходный и переменовывет временный. В этом случае шансов на то, что файл будет прочитан "неполностью" - мало. В линуксе, пока файл открыт процессом, он не удаляется (точнее, удаляется имя файла в таблице, но не сам файл). И когда последний дескриптор будет закрыт, файл будет физически удален (но на самом деле врядли кто то его будет затирать нулями. Просто поменят блоки как свободные). Этот способ дает ещё один плюс - если читателей несколько и они читают "долго", то они могут читать "старую версию".

Но использовать для синхронизации такой метод не стоит - файловая система не даст Вам гарантий, что если одна программа записала данные, то другая уже это увидела.

**UDP**

> Дополнительный вопрос - есть ли гарантия, что читатели будут видеть изменения в том же порядке, в каком их вносит писатель (т.е. стоит ли ещё добавлять какой-то порядковый номер записи помимо контрольной суммы)

Я бы на это не надеялся. Да, вполне возможно, что для определенной файловой системы это будет выполнятся, но я нигде не видел таких гарантий.

Comment: Венда как бы тоже там у них в требованиях.. ) Хотя почему бы и нет, в винде читатели повторят попытки просто.

Comment: "венда" не указана в вопросе:). Но, учитывая, что у них там под низом стараются быть posix, то все должно работать. Но это нужно проверить.

Comment: Пожалуй удовлетворюсь вашим ответом. А по поводу насилия над ФС (соседний ответ), что думаете? Так ли страшен черт как его малютка?

Comment: тут такое дело, что одному насилие, то другому очень редко. Вполне возможно, что торрент клиенты смотрят на Ваш код и тихонько хихикают, "это он "насилует"".

Я бы лично брал базу (или что то типа "редис") и использовал. Тут и гарантии построже, и плюшки разные. И насилие выдержит посерьезнее.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте пайпы или сокеты. Нет совершенно никакого смысла насиловать ФС.

Разумеется, API сокетов разный на разных платформах, но идеологически они эквивалентны.

Для Qt есть обертка - `QLocalSocket`.

Самый быстрый способ IPC - совместное отображение файла в память.

А ваш способ - дичайший велосипед.

Comment: Не, ну это не интересно, на сокетах всякий сможет )

Comment: @VladimirGamalian на ФС у вас может быть очень много гарантий (если ФС локальная) и очень мало (если это сетевая кластерная ФС типа ceph или OrangeFS, в которых даже блокировки на файл нет). Написание адаптеров на все случаи жизни займет у вас пару месяцев и все равно нормально работать не будет.

Comment: Т.е. оставить вариант с `optimistic read` и контрольной суммой, и не париться?